# How to create SWF movie from C# application?

Tags: c#, adobe, flash

I'm working on C# application where I get some user input, so I'd like to save it as animation to SWF.

I searched the web for some open library to do that, but I've found only dead links. Is there any open library for that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The input is some scetch, which I have in vector form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create swf files. Then you will need to generate it with adobe's SDK.
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK
And there's an open source flash editor project using java + adobe air may helps you.
http://code.google.com/p/minibuilder/

Comment: And http://www.libming.org/ Ming is a library for generating Macromedia Flash files (.swf), written in C.

Comment: Yes, I've checked - it has C# bindings too.

Thank you, sindney

Comment: I rechecked - inspite of C# is mentioned, there is no C# bindings in distribution. Also there is no Windows version of this library. So it isn't what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I overlooked this project, but there is SwfDotNet.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfdotnet/

It seems to be almost what I need, I'll look it through tomorrow.